# Facebook real-time api: registered for user/likes but not receiving updates

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have created a Facebook real-time api subscription for one of my apps. I subscribed to the `user` object and the `likes` field. I have verified that my original subscription was successful by requesting my current subscriptions and I received the right info back from facebook:

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "object": "user",
         "callback_url": "http://mydomain.com/myapp/callback.php",
         "fields": [
            "likes"
         ],
         "active": true
      }
   ]
}
```

If I understand correctly, I should receive a callback whenever a person who has authorized my app likes something on Facebook.

First question, is that correct?

If so, I authorized my app on my personal Facebook page, and then liked https://www.facebook.com/frontalot's page, but I didn't receive a callback.

Any ideas why?

EDIT:

One of the proposed answers mentioned that the docs say the likes connection is not supported yet, but this is what the documentation says:

> Here are the list of User connections to which you can subscribe:
>   feed, friends, activities, interests, music, books, movies,
>   television, likes, checkins, location, events.
>
> You can't subscribe to these User connections yet: home, tagged, posts, photos, albums, videos, groups, notes, inbox, outbox, updates,
>   accounts.

So it says I can subscribe to the likes connection.

Comment: Which permissions did you ask for? You need to ask for `user_likes` for this to work I think.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/) the `likes` connection is not yet supported. If you would like to record a like that happens on your site you can use `FB.Event.subscribe` mentioned [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/).

Comment: The documentation says I can subscribe to likes... 

Here are the list of User connections to which you can subscribe: feed, friends, activities, interests, music, books, movies, television, likes, checkins, location, events.

Comment: Also, I'm not trying to record likes on my site. I've got a list of users who have authorized my app, and I want to know if/when they Like a certain company's page on Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

Even I had some issues with the callback not getting fired. You could subscribe to user's feed. And also you should give permission scope as read_stream while login. You will get the call back saying that there is a change in the user's feed. You can then query for that feed and get the likes.